# Using a model to get the fields for another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have one model to define the fields in my system

```
class MetadataField(models.Model):
    FIELD_TYPE = (
        ('TXT', "Text"),
        ('CB', 'Checkbox'),
        ('DD', 'DropDown')
    )
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=FIELD_TYPE, default='TXT')
    workflow = models.ManyToManyField('Workflow')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Each field is associated with a workflow. Here is my workflow model

```
class Workflow(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have a project model.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    workflow = models.ForeignKey('Workflow')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now say there are 4 projects. Each project is associated with a workflow

Project 1 : Workflow 1
Project 2 : Workflow 1
Project 3 : Workflow 2
Project 4 : Workflow 3

I want each project to have it's information (metadata). The metadata fields for every project should come from the fields created (in field model) for the associated workflow. It is like a form where the relevant fields are coming from the created fields and user can enter the value for each of those fields. How do I write a model to store this metadata? Will I have to write a separate model for every workflow?

Comment: You use a `ManyToManyFielde`, so a `Project` here can have zero, one, or more `Workflow`s, likely you want to use a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Yes. I changed it. Thanks for pointing it out.